# how to save a rounded version on image with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick, minimagick

I want to save a round shape version of every profile image. Is there any way by which I can save a round or circle shape image for all images. I know I can do it with css in front end but I want to save it for other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example for the [clip_path](https://rmagick.github.io/draw.html#clip_path) method in Magick:Draw. You'll also need [define_clip_path](https://rmagick.github.io/draw.html#define_clip_path) and [roundrectangle](https://rmagick.github.io/draw.html#roundrectangle).